How to load in javascript files in shadow DOM
I'm trying to get my slider component to work. For this I need to load in 2 javascript files:
<script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=6602cf158fccd6b1f9c2c75c" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

This is my slider component inside my components.js file:
/* ======================================================================================== */
/* ============================================================== SLIDER */
const sliderTemplate = document.createElement('template');
sliderTemplate.innerHTML = `

<link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/diamond-heart.webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<section class="section-wat-we-doen">
    <div class="spacing">
        <div id="w-node-_51899271-5376-bab9-28c6-15a90fc8430a-f9c2c767" class="holder">
            <div id="w-node-_51899271-5376-bab9-28c6-15a90fc8430b-f9c2c767" class="above-title white">Wat we doen</div>
            <h2 class="white">Zodat jij rust vind</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-delay="4000" data-animation="slide" class="slider w-slider" data-autoplay="false" data-easing="ease" data-hide-arrows="false" data-disable-swipe="false" data-autoplay-limit="0" data-nav-spacing="3" data-duration="500" data-infinite="true">
            <div class="mask w-slider-mask">
                <div class="slide w-slide">
                    <div class="w-layout-grid grid-2cols">
                        <div id="w-node-_51899271-5376-bab9-28c6-15a90fc84313-f9c2c767" class="holder"><img src="images/starting-the-classes-2023-11-27-04-53-47-utc-1_1.webp" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 94vw, (max-width: 767px) 92vw, 94vw" srcset="images/starting-the-classes-2023-11-27-04-53-47-utc-1_1starting-the-classes-2023-11-27-04-53-47-utc-1.webp 500w, images/starting-the-classes-2023-11-27-04-53-47-utc-1_1starting-the-classes-2023-11-27-04-53-47-utc-1.webp 800w, images/starting-the-classes-2023-11-27-04-53-47-utc-1_1starting-the-classes-2023-11-27-04-53-47-utc-1.webp 1080w, images/starting-the-classes-2023-11-27-04-53-47-utc-1_1.webp 1920w" alt="People in a circle" class="image-full-width"></div>
                            <div id="w-node-_51899271-5376-bab9-28c6-15a90fc84315-f9c2c767" class="holder">
                                <h2 class="orange">Advaita Vedanta</h2>
                                <p class="white">Tijdens een gesprek, vergadering en voor langere tijd tijdenswoon- of retraite Diamond Heart wijst voortdurendnaar je ware aard, die niet je lichaam of geest is, maar jouwtijdloze ware natuur, geheel in de Advaita traditie.</p>
                                <a href="wat-we-doen.html" class="button textual w-button">Lees meer<span class="button-arrow"> </span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="slide w-slide">
                    <div class="w-layout-grid grid-2cols">
                        <div id="w-node-_51899271-5376-bab9-28c6-15a90fc8431e-f9c2c767" class="holder"><img src="images/relaxing-on-workshops-2023-11-27-05-12-22-utc-1_1.webp" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 94vw, (max-width: 767px) 92vw, 94vw" srcset="images/relaxing-on-workshops-2023-11-27-05-12-22-utc-1_1relaxing-on-workshops-2023-11-27-05-12-22-utc-1.webp 500w, images/relaxing-on-workshops-2023-11-27-05-12-22-utc-1_1relaxing-on-workshops-2023-11-27-05-12-22-utc-1.webp 800w, images/relaxing-on-workshops-2023-11-27-05-12-22-utc-1_1relaxing-on-workshops-2023-11-27-05-12-22-utc-1.webp 1080w, images/relaxing-on-workshops-2023-11-27-05-12-22-utc-1_1.webp 1920w" alt="People sleeping in a circle" class="image-full-width"></div>
                        <div id="w-node-_51899271-5376-bab9-28c6-15a90fc84320-f9c2c767" class="holder">
                            <h2 class="orange">Advaita</h2>
                            <p class="white">In weekendbijeenkomsten, residentieel of retraites eigentijds teksten en klassieke Advaita-teksten worden gebruikt als vehikel en hulp die altijd wijst naar wat je werkelijk bent, wat dat niet is je lichaam of geest, maar je tijdloze ware aard.</p>
                            <a href="wat-we-doen.html" class="button textual w-button">Lees meer<span class="button-arrow"> </span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide w-slide">
                    <div class="w-layout-grid grid-2cols">
                        <div id="w-node-_51899271-5376-bab9-28c6-15a90fc84329-f9c2c767" class="holder"><img src="images/meditating-during-session-2023-11-27-05-00-50-utc-1_1.webp" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 94vw, (max-width: 767px) 92vw, 94vw" srcset="images/meditating-during-session-2023-11-27-05-00-50-utc-1_1meditating-during-session-2023-11-27-05-00-50-utc-1.webp 500w, images/meditating-during-session-2023-11-27-05-00-50-utc-1_1meditating-during-session-2023-11-27-05-00-50-utc-1.webp 800w, images/meditating-during-session-2023-11-27-05-00-50-utc-1_1meditating-during-session-2023-11-27-05-00-50-utc-1.webp 1080w, images/meditating-during-session-2023-11-27-05-00-50-utc-1_1.webp 1920w" alt="People meditating in a circle" class="image-full-width"></div>
                        <div id="w-node-_51899271-5376-bab9-28c6-15a90fc8432b-f9c2c767" class="holder">
                            <h2 class="orange">Nataraj</h2>
                            <p class="white">Een residentie of toevluchtsoord is als een snelkookpan en geweldig vuur waar alle illusoire ideeën worden verbrand, weggesneden en... verdampt. De hindoegod Nataraj symboliseerde dit mechanisme terwijl Shiva danst terwijl de vlammen wegbranden onwetendheid.</p>
                            <a href="wat-we-doen.html" class="button textual w-button">Lees meer<span class="button-arrow"> </span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left-arrow w-slider-arrow-left"><img src="images/arrow-white-right_1.svg" loading="lazy" alt=""></div>
            <div class="right-arrow w-slider-arrow-right"><img src="images/arrow-white-right_1.svg" loading="lazy" alt=""></div>
            <div class="slide-nav w-slider-nav w-round"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
`

class Slider extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        shadowRoot.appendChild(sliderTemplate.content);
    }
}
customElements.define('comp-slider', Slider);

How ever I can't seem to get this to work no matter how much I research and play around with the code.
If possible a simple solution to load in the two javascript files so the slider functionality is restored.

You'll have to properly import the modules you need. Web components don't work in a way that simply loading a JavaScript transforms the HTML. Also you want to clone the nodes: sliderTemplate.content.cloneNode(true)

@connexo im not sure what you mean with any of this. Im pretty new to Javascript ^-^

Sounds like you did not create this component yourself. Have you verified that Web Component actually supports shadowDOM?

The component itself works, i can place  in my HTML pages and the component will show. But in this case the slider uses extra javascript to work and I can't seem to connect the two neccesary javascript files to the component

Try to add script to html where you used comp-slider elements.
<script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=6602cf158fccd6b1f9c2c75c" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<comp-slider></comp-slider>

Or you can use document.createElement('script') in components.js
var script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=6602cf158fccd6b1f9c2c75c'
var script2 = document.createElement('script')
script2.src = 'js/webflow.js'
shadowRoot.appendChild(script)
shadowRoot.appendChild(script2)


This does not work :( I tried adding the scripts under and above in the HTMl file, also in the component code I tried to place it everywhere but I can't seem to get it to work. Thank you for your suggestion though!
